# MATLAB - Bode plot

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

How to plot the following transfer function?

[image: pic]

```
A = 5;
num = [A];
den = [];
fun = tf(num, den);
bode(fun);
```

How to input the bottom line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s= tf([1 0],1) % s contains the tf object with `s` transfer function
system= 5/(1+s/w1)/(1+s/w2)/(1+s/w3) % this works due to the operator overloading
bode(system)
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.